# jqGrid require on custom selectList

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, jqgrid

I am trying to require user input on dynamic select list. I have the editrules:{require:true} in the ColModel but the pop up doesn't require the user to select an item that doesn't have the value of ''. The first option of the select List will always be..

```
 <select value="">Choose an Item</select>
```

My model for the column is

```
{ name: 'ProductId', index: 'ProductId', width: 100, key: false,  editable: true, align: "right", edittype: "select", editoptions: mySelectList, editrules: {required:true, }, formoptions:{elprefix:'(*)'} }
```

mySelectList is populated with

```
mySelectList = {
        dataInit: function (element, row) {
            var listItems = [];
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetSelectList", "Home")',
                success: function (res) {
                    listItems = res;
                },
                async: false
            });
            //listItems = [{val: someVal, text: someText}, ...];
            var selList = formatSelectList(listItems);
            //selList = '<option value="someVal">someText</option>....';
            $(element).prop("name", "System");
            $(element).append(selList);
            var LineId = $("#grid").jqGrid('getRowData', row.rowId).LineId;
            $(element).val(LineId);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please elaborate more, what kind of dynamic select list? when do you populates the select list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it would be easier to just write my own check before the form is submitted, so I wrote my own function.

```
$.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
    beforeSubmit: validateForm,
    recreateForm: true,
    closeAfterAdd: true,
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    reloadAfterSubmit: true,
    saveKey: [true, 13]
});
```

This is my validation function.

```
function validateForm(postdata, formid)
{
    var message, 
        success = true;

    if(isEmpty(postdata.ProductId))
    {
        success = false;
        message = "Please select a Product";
    }

    return [success, message];
}

function isEmpty(obj){ 
     return (
         typeof(obj) == "undefined" || 
         obj == null || 
         obj == NaN ||
         obj == ""
     ); 
}
```